# How to use a user-input function with another function?

Tags: c, function, pointers, recursion, parameters

I have these two functions, ReadData which is suppose to take user input for three numbers, and the other function ComputeSum which is suppose to take the values entered by the user and add them together. I am trying to assign the result of the ComputeSum function to the **total** variable but it fails to print the correct total. Can someone explain what is causing this to occur?

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <ctype.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <math.h>


void ReadData(int *x,int *y,int *z);
int ComputeSum(int x,int y,int z);


int main()
{
  int x, y, z;
  int total;

  ReadData(&x, &y, &z);
  printf("\n");

  total = ComputeSum(x,y,z);

  printf("The total is: %d", total);



  printf("\n\n");

system("PAUSE");
return 0;

}




void ReadData(int *x,int *y,int *z)
{
printf("Enter three numbers : ");
scanf("%d %d %d", &x, &y, &z );
printf("\n");

ComputeSum(x,y,z);

return ;
}

int ComputeSum(int x,int y,int z)
{
int Sum = x+y+z;

return Sum;
}

___________________________________________________________________

     **Sample Output**

 Enter three numbers : 5 5 5


The total is: 8869621

Press any key to continue . . .
```

---

Answer (score 1):

This line in `ReadData()` is incorrect

```
scanf("%d %d %d", &x, &y, &z );
```

It should be

```
scanf("%d %d %d", x, y, z );
```

because the three arguments are already pointers. The following line in the same function

```
ComputeSum(x,y,z);
```

is also incorrect, it should be

```
ComputeSum(*x, *y, *z);
```

But it is not even necessary since you don't use the result, and it is called in `main` anyway.

Please enable compiler warnings and take notice of them, both these faults generate warnings.

Comment: The call to `ComputeSum` inside Readdata is completely useless and can simply be dropped. The line that says `total = ComputeSum(x,y,z)` is correct as-is.

Answer (score 1):

In function `void ReadData(int *x,int *y,int *z);`

```
scanf("%d %d %d", &x, &y, &z );
```

`x`,`y` and `z` are already pointers so you don't need to pass their address , just pass pointers-

```
scanf("%d %d %d", x, y, z );
```

I don't understand why you call `ComputeSum()` in `ReadData()` as you call it already in `main()` .No need of that.

```
void ReadData(int *x,int *y,int *z)
{
   //your code
   ComputeSum(x,y,z);    // Why ?? No need of it 
   return ;
 }
```

Answer (score 0):

- Here is your solution,

  ```
  #include <stdio.h>
  #include <stdlib.h>
  #include <ctype.h>
  #include <string.h>
  #include <math.h>

  void ReadData(int *x,int *y,int *z);
  int ComputeSum(int x,int y,int z);

  int main()
  {
    int x, y, z;
    int total;

    ReadData(&x, &y, &z);
    printf("\n");
    printf("\n\n");

    system("PAUSE");
    return 0;

    }
    void ReadData(int *x,int *y,int *z)
    {
        printf("Enter three numbers : ");
        scanf("%d %d %d", x, y, z );
        printf("\n");

        int total = ComputeSum(*x,*y,*z);
        printf("The total is: %d", total);
        return ;
    }

    int ComputeSum(int x,int y,int z)
    {
        int Sum = x+y+z;
        return Sum;
    }
  ```
- Call ComputeSum function only from ReadData like this,

  ```
    int total = ComputeSum(*x,*y,*z);
  ```